# Azure - Bicep deployment - API version changing when deploying

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I'm having a weird issue when deploying resources using Bicep that I'm hoping someone can share some light on.

For several resources I am deploying, I am trying to deploy with the non-preview versions of the API, for example:

```
resource logAnalyticsWorkspace 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2022-10-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      name: sku
    }
    retentionInDays: logAnalyticsRetentionInDays
  }

  tags: tags
}
```

When I deploy this, it deploys succesfully, however when I check in the portal,the Log Analytics workspace has defaulted to **"apiVersion": "2021-12-01-preview"**.

This is occurring for a few different resources such as API Management as well. Can anyone give any insight on why this occurs and if there's a way to not have it occur?

Thanks,

Comment: Where do you check in the portal for the Version? If it’s via Export template I guess it is automatically generated and does simply not remember your deployment as the version refers to the api not the resources.

Comment: Yeah it doesnt really matter to be honest.

Comment: Ahh okay. So what you're saying is that the export template is not representative of what I have actually deployed. It just by default gets the latest version of the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any insight on why this occurs and if there's a way to not have it occur.

- Preview versions are similar to updated versions released by the team prior to gathering feedback or verifying the functionality.
- Version will be automatically set to the latest/preview version after deployment, depending on the properties/fields provided in the bicep resource type.
- A few Azure Services may no longer support non-preview versions when deployed using bicep. Use Azure CLI in that case.

  *In the* `Json/parameters` *file, every resource type includes a* `version` *parameter. If required, provide the required version.*

[image]

[image]

**Note:** I would suggest you not to use non preview versions as some of them doesn't have the updated fields & functionality.

Refer MSDoc: [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/change-log/service/apiversionsets) & [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.operationalinsights/allversions)